# Maxwell said that for a gas , the 'coefficient of friction is independent of density' but his equation says the opposite

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

As the developer of statistical mechanics, James Clerk Maxwell considered the behavior of individual gas molecules. Prior to his studies of electromagnetism, he did an experiment to verify his prediction that the density of a gas (its pressure) does not change its friction (viscosity). However in the original manuscript here:

https://archive.org/details/scientificpapers01maxw/page/390/mode/2up?ref=ol&view=theater

On page 391 , his equation 24 indicates that:

$\mu = 1/3 \rho l \nu$

where
$\mu$ is coefficient of friction

$\rho$ is density

$l$ is mean path length

$\nu$ is the mean velocity

Clearly, the coefficient of friction is a function of density but in the next sentence he said it is not. WTF?!

Can someone straighten me out because I am missing SOMETHING BIG.

Answer (score 2):

The mean free path in a dilute gas is inversely proportional to the density at fixed temperature. If the density increases, the mean free path decreases such that their product - and therefore $\mu$ - is constant.

Comment: thank you. ok, if the mean free path length per unit time decreases, then shouldn't velocity decrease as well?

Comment: @aquagremlin Where did “per unit time” come from? For an ideal gas, the mean speed is purely a function of temperature, so at fixed temperature it doesn’t change with density.

Comment: ok, my error.  mean free path length is distance between collisions-dunno how I mixed up time in there.